# VisualStudio: connect to my own git server

Tags: git, visual-studio

I'm using the latest version of VisualStudio. I've created a first project and now I would add it to my own repo on my own git server.

In the `Team Explorer > Repository Settings` tab I entered the following:

```
git://aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd/path/to/my/repo
```

where `aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd` is the IP of my git server.
When I try to push a commit it shows this error:

> Error during the publishing of the current branch in the remote repository: Git failed with a fatal error.

The orginal message is in Italian.
Do you see any evidence of errors - provided the address and the path are correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the git protocol you must create a git-daemon-export-ok file as described here:
https://git-scm.com/book/it/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols (section:
The Git Protocol).